# Table missing after index:reset

Tags: reindex, magento2.1.6

I had been looking around for solution for the pass 2 weeks and nothing seems to help. Recently, i had a few indexes that are always in "processing" status and whenever I try to reindex these indexes are always skipped.

After doing some search, i came across a solution to run indexer:reset and run indexer:reindex again. However, this make things worst. now the design_config_grid table missing and i was unable to create new table using sql script as suggested in another post.

Situation at this moment:-
When I execute reindex, I get the following:-
Design Config Grid indexer process unknown error:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 
'.design_config_grid_flat' doesn't exist, query was: CREATE 
TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `design_config_grid_flat` (
  `entity_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID' ,
  `store_website_id` int NULL COMMENT 'Store_website_id' ,
  `store_group_id` int NULL COMMENT 'Store_group_id' ,
  `store_id` int NULL COMMENT 'Store_id' ,
  `theme_theme_id` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Theme_theme_id' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  INDEX `DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_STORE_WEBSITE_ID` (`store_website_id`),
  INDEX `DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_STORE_GROUP_ID` (`store_group_id`),
  INDEX `DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
  FULLTEXT `DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_THEME_THEME_ID` (`theme_theme_id`)
) COMMENT='design_config_grid_flat' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 
COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping.
Product EAV index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping.
Stock index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping.
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:04

The following is the index status:-
Design Config Grid:                                Reindex required
Customer Grid:                                     Ready
Category Products:                                 Ready
Product Categories:                                Ready
Product Price:                                     Processing
Product EAV:                                       Processing
Stock:                                             Processing
Catalog Rule Product:                              Ready
Catalog Product Rule:                              Ready
Catalog Search:                                    Ready

Please help, this is a new project assigned to me and i am in serious trouble here if i cannot solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

please run the same command in mysql as: goto table theme delete all the tuples of non required theme except magento _blank _luma backend and your custom theme you are going to use than change the theme id in core config data there is a row as : design/theme/theme_id   change value of next column to  the required theme id and than run :

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Answer (score 0):

I have a one final solution for this that works

go to phpmyadmin
run SQL command DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `design_config_grid_flat`

again run the command to create the table

```
CREATE 
TABLE IF NOT EXISTS design_config_grid_flat (
entity_id int UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID' ,
store_website_id int NULL COMMENT 'Store_website_id' ,
store_group_id int NULL COMMENT 'Store_group_id' ,
store_id int NULL COMMENT 'Store_id' ,
theme_theme_id varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Theme_theme_id' ,
PRIMARY KEY (entity_id),
INDEX DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_STORE_WEBSITE_ID (store_website_id),
INDEX DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_STORE_GROUP_ID (store_group_id),
INDEX DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_STORE_ID (store_id),
FULLTEXT DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_FLAT_THEME_THEME_ID (theme_theme_id)
) COMMENT='design_config_grid_flat' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 
COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
```

this will drop the corrupted table and regenerate the table and it will work fine than.